# C++ 11 : decltype behaviour of T and T& derivation [ behaviour distinction between both ]

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
int i = 12;

decltype(i) x4; // type is int

decltype((i)) x5; // type is int&
```

We know from C++ fundementals that `i` is lvaue already.
now `decltype(i)` is equal to type of expression `i` which is natually `int`.
Now as per spec/standard `(i)` is also an lvalue and `decltype((i))` should also in some way inspect type of expression `(i)` which is lvalue and is same as `i` which is also lvalue. But why the standard suddenly requires `T&` type ?

This is very confusing. because if it was `decltype((i)&)` then I agree this means `decltype` of `int&` would have been much more clear and precise. I am a bit lost here as to why `i` and `(i)` both of which resolve to lvalue type result in different types of `T` and `T&`.

Comment: Hope the linked duplicate answers your question. And [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/4z8han/decltypee_decltypee/)'s another discussion about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: [decltype specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)

First of all, `decltype` has different behavior on *entities* and *expressions*.

> > 1) If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a structured binding, then decltype yields the referenced type (described in the specification of the structured binding declaration).
> >     *(since C++17)*
>
> 2) If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access expression, then decltype yields the type of the entity named by this expression. If there is no such entity, or if the argument names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed.
>
> 3) If the argument is any other expression of type T, and
>   - a) if the value category of expression is xvalue, then decltype yields T&&;
>   - b) if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields T&;
>   - c) if the value category of expression is prvalue, then decltype yields T.

And this line below:

> Note that **if the name of an object is parenthesized, it is treated as an ordinary lvalue expression**, thus `decltype(x)` and `decltype((x))` are often different types.

So according to rule 2, `i` is an *entity*, so decltype yields the exact type of `i`, which is `int`. According to rule 3 and the specially exgracted line (above), `(i)` is not an entity but an **lvalue expression**, thus decltype yields an lvalue reference, namely `int&`.

(`&(i)` and `(i)++` are valid expressions so `(i)` is an lvalue)